# Firestore: Invalid package reference in library

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, google-cloud-firestore, lint

After updating to `com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:16.0.0` I get the following lint error:

```
  Error: Invalid package reference in library; not included in Android: javax.naming.directory. Referenced from io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.JndiResolver. [InvalidPackage]
  Error: Invalid package reference in library; not included in Android: javax.naming. Referenced from io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.JndiResolver. [InvalidPackage]
```

Seems that the `grpc` dependency is making `lint` unhappy. How can I solve this?

Comment: It seems the @nicopicp answer is correct, can you accept it as correct?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can remove this error by setting the following content in a `lint.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lint>
    <issue id="InvalidPackage">
        <ignore path="*/io.grpc/grpc-core/*"/>
    </issue>
</lint>
```

The `lint.xml` should be at the root of your *application* module.

The advantage over demoting the error to a warning is that if you later happen to add a dependency which really have an invalid package, you will still get the error.

Comment: Thanks for the more specific answer!  Agree that's better.

Comment: It seems the answer is correct, can you accept it as correct @SamStern ?

Comment: Do you know the reason why this would happen?

Comment: I'm a little confused by the path, why do you have `grpc-core`, this does not seem to appear in the error.

Comment: Where is `lint.xml`? Do I create it myself? Where is it?

Comment: @Sheepdogsheep the invalid package is referenced by `io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.JndiResolver` (see the error message). The path I used was the one matching the JAR containing this class

Comment: @salyela you have to create the file yourself, usually at the root of your application module. The documentation states you can create it at the root of your _project_ though. See https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint#pref

Answer (score 18):

This error should be safe to ignore. You can downgrade all `InvalidPackage` errors to warnings using this block:

```
android {

    // ...

    lintOptions {
        warning 'InvalidPackage'
    }
}
```

Comment: Why it's safe to ignore it?

Comment: Using this block exactly where??