# Gradle lint & test build error - JAXBException and Invalid package reference in library

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-databinding, circleci

Today i was trying to add an Android project to CIRCLE CI where i'm running ./gradlew lint test as a check for builds to pass. The issue is that i got some annoying errors and i'm struggling from hours to solve them:

on my local machine, i get: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException`

and on CIRCLE CI the following error is thrown:

> The first 3 errors (out of 10) were:
>     /home/circleci/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.activation/activation/1.1.1/485de3a253e23f645037828c07f1d7f1af40763a/activation-1.1.1.jar: Error: Invalid package reference in library; not included in Android: java.awt.datatransfer. Referenced from javax.activation.ActivationDataFlavor. [InvalidPackage]
>     /home/circleci/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.activation/activation/1.1.1/485de3a253e23f645037828c07f1d7f1af40763a/activation-1.1.1.jar: Error: Invalid package reference in library; not included in Android: java.awt.event. Referenced from com.sun.activation.viewers.TextEditor. [InvalidPackage]
>     /home/circleci/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.activation/activation/1.1.1/485de3a253e23f645037828c07f1d7f1af40763a/activation-1.1.1.jar: Error: Invalid package reference in library; not included in Android: java.awt. Referenced from com.sun.activation.viewers.ImageViewer. [InvalidPackage]

I am using databinding in my android project, together with livedata and androidx. I've been searching the web for hours and nothing helped me. I tried to silence the errors with:

`lintOptions {
        abortOnError true
        lintConfig file("lint.xml")
    }`

and lint.xml:

```
<lint>
<issue id="InvalidPackage">
    <ignore path="**/activation*.jar"/>
</issue>
</lint>
```

Thanks in advance for any help. Please ask for more information if needed!

Comment: It seems you have followed the other SO advice here to remove the error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50159255/firestore-invalid-package-reference-in-library. However, that post seems to indicate that the place you keep lint.xml is important (it should be at root of application module, not project). Can you plz share your project structure, and where that file is kept?

Comment: Also, can you please try replaceing <ignore path="**/activation*.jar"/> with <ignore path="**/javax.activation/activation/*"/>  Notice here we are more specific about the parent directories of activation ignore, and we're ignoring all files (not just jars)

Comment: @Parzie i tried also with "*/javax.activation/activation/" and it's still not working. My lint.xml file location is project/app/lint.xml

Comment: is your github repo public? i.e. can you share a link to it so I can clone it locally and test?

Comment: Unfortunately it's a private repo at my organization

Comment: Ok no problem, I'm going to try to replicate your issue in a minimal android project (in a public github repo + circleci) and will get back to you later today

Comment: I suggest to use DataBinding and a BindingAdapter in your project to easily reproduce the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Gabi I was able to replicate the issue in a public github repo + circleci, and resolve it.

Please see the following Public android-practice github repo commit history: https://github.com/ejparz/android-practice/commits/master

As part of this commit I got the corresponding CircleCi build working properly.

**Commit**: https://github.com/ejparz/android-practice/commit/b5f4b20a2adc3ef828153b39869f766ee7e9920e

**Build**: https://circleci.com/gh/ejparz/android-practice/6

---

Then I added an invalid package (javax.activation:activation), and got the same errors as you in the corresponding circleci build

**Commit**: https://github.com/ejparz/android-practice/commit/ca6f502170439e28cbcf269eac302369a282d7d0

**Build**: https://circleci.com/gh/ejparz/android-practice/7

Notice the build has the same errors you report 
**Error: Invalid package reference in library; not included in Android: java.awt.datatransfer. Referenced from javax.activation.ActivationDataFlavor** etc.

---

Then, I fix the error by adding a lint.xml file at ***the root of application module***

**Commit**: https://github.com/ejparz/android-practice/commit/7e9f7ca030370570e55c34201fd6f568e049279e

**Build**: https://circleci.com/gh/ejparz/android-practice/8

The build now succeeds!

---

Please Note that the location of the lint.xml file is very important. It CANNOT go at root of project. It must go at root of module (As indicated in this other SO post: [Firestore: Invalid package reference in library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50159255/firestore-invalid-package-reference-in-library))

Please let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I followed your advices and my lint.xml file was set up correctly. I have managed to run `./gradlew lint test` locally with success by setting `org.gradle.java.home=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home` in project/gradle.properties so the wrapper will use the same JDK as Android Studio. But here is another problem, how do I configure this to run on CIRCLE CI? because this path only works on my machine

Comment: I updated the circle image to `circleci/android:api-29` and i managed to pass the build. Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by your JDK version (A better explanation in this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43574427) )

On a Mac you can try to use brew to install JDK8 which solves the problem.

To do so:

1. Install Brew from this [website](https://brew.sh/)
2. Run `brew tap adoptopenjdk/openjdk` to enable adopto open jdk formulas (The officials are no longer available).
3. Run `brew cask install adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8`to install open jdk 8
4. Run `brew install jenv` to Install jenv (Java version manager)
5. Run `echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.jenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc` and
   `echo 'eval "$(jenv init -)"' >> ~/.zshrc` if you use ZSH or `echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.jenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile` and
   `echo 'eval "$(jenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile` if you use BASH
6. Close and Open the console again
7. Run `jenv add Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home` to add jdk version 8
8. Run `jenv versions` to list your installed versions
9. Run `jenv global <name of version>` to change to another one

Find out more about jenv in this [website](https://www.jenv.be/) you can also configure java versions by folder instead of globally